# Azure App service Web Page cached at client side

Tags: javascript, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have a Asp.Net Core + Vue js  (SPA) application hosted on Azure App service.
Since sometime, we observed that changes deployed to production are not reflected on client side.
After further investigation, we found that the html page rendered on client side doesn't have latest script source url. We do add unique Id to our script src, but it looks like the entire page version is cached on browser, hence latest scripts are not rendered to client.

Any idea if anybody saw similar behaviour?

I tried to add following cache tags, however it doesn't helps to prevent such behavior.
Most of complains we got are from Chrome / Edge browsers.

[image]

Here is the sample of script tag we have

[image]

Comment: I think it would be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1276499/how-do-i-disable-app-cache-for-azure-app-service | Just a question, after you change anything, do you perform a restart?

Comment: @KKI, we use swap-slot approach. so every time new code is deployed, we start the slot and deploy the changes and swap the slot.

Comment: Is there any cdn service that might caused the caching? like azure cdn or front door, if so you can try directly accessing the app service URL to verify the problem. If not you can verify if the problem originated from Chrome by checking the Chrome debug network to see if the document request is indeed cached.

Comment: each client's browser will cache the front-end (that's the single-page)  The way I worked around this is to call an endpoint to get the version.  If it doesn't match the front-end's version, I trigger a reload() so the page gets refreshed.  Ex: if (!sessionStorage.getItem("hasReloaded")) { 
this.GetVersion()
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.version = result.version;
    if (this.frontEndVersion != this.version) {
     
     
      sessionStorage.setItem("hasReloaded", "true");
    
      location.reload();
    }

  });
}

Comment: Each time you publish a change, though, you need to update both front-end version and back-end version.  (They need to match.... I just keep them hard-coded in frontend/backend controllers.)